# Jenkins Addon in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a parameterized project. With the variable VAR1.

I'm using the the `Xray for JIRA Jenkins Plugin` for Jenkins. There you can fill four parameters:

- JIRA Instance
- Issues
- Filter
- File Path

I'm new to Jenkins but what I have learned so far, that you can't fill this fields with environment variables. Something like

Issues: ${VAR1}   - doesn't work.

So I thought I can do this with a pipeline. When I click on Pipeline Syntax and chose `step: General Build Step` I can choose `Xray: Cucumber Features Export Task`. Then I fill the fields with my environment variable and click `Generate Pipeline Script` The output is as follows:

```
step <object of type com.xpandit.plugins.xrayjenkins.task.XrayExportBuilder>
```

That doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: is it possible post the pipeline? I'm not sure if I understood your question

Answer (score 0):

All you're doing is OK, but what you want is not supported by Jenkins whether it is pipeline or not, since the parameters' load is happening prior to the pipeline-flow or the definition of the ${VAR1}.

You can try to overcome this by defining the 'Issues' value as a pipeline internal value instead of a parameter and base it on the ${VAR1} value.

If it must be a parameter, use 2 jobs where one defines the value of 'Issues' based on a the ${VAR1} and pass it to the other job that gets the 'Issues' as a fixed value.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I understand, that I can't solve my problem like I tried. The problem: Jira is calling Jenkins with the parameter VAR1. Then I want to export the Issue from Jira with the VAR1 parameter. When I do this with two Jobs, how can I define a variable in a Jenkins project which I can use in the field "Issues" from the addon?

Comment: You define it in the called job the same way you define it in the calling job. If you don't know how to do it with pipeline, do it as a simple job instead.
The 'pipeline syntax' doesn't support all type of parameters - I've encountered this as well for other parameter-types.

Comment: Hmm ok. My english is not the best so maybe I don't understand you right. Sorry. I don't understand how your solution work. I can use this Xray Addon as a build step. There are four fields I have to fill. If I fill in something like ${VAR1} the addon use "${VAR1} and not the value. So which kind of variable are passed to the second job that I can use for the Xray buildstep?

Comment: When you call a job from within a job, you can pass 'predefined parameters'  and set something like: 'Issues=${VER1}